# Hauser & Wirth garden plan

Tags: perennials, fall-gardening

Is it at public source to get Hauser & Wirth garden plan made by Piet Oudolf? I would recreate this scene in my garden.

[image]

Comment: At least some of the info you refer to is online. https://www.vogue.com/slideshow/piet-oudolf-at-work-phaidon-book  What research have you done?

Answer (score 2):

Hauser & Wirth have published Piet Oudolf's garden plan on their [Oudolf Field](https://www.hauserwirth.com/news/2269-oudolf-field/) web page.  I have marked where I believe the picture in your question is taken from.

[image: Landscape proposal for the Oudolf Field at Durslade Farm, hand drawn on paper in color]
*Landscape proposal for the Oudolf Field at Durslade Farm, Photo by Alex Delfanne*

A better picture János found themselves:
[image: Another photograph of the garden plan, legible, upside-down, and only partially in frame]

I emailed the garden asking for a legible garden plan, and they gave me a reply:

> Thank you for contacting us. We are delighted to hear your interest in the Oudolf Gardens.
>
> Unfortunately, we don’t have the digital copy of the plan to share,
> however it is included in the dedicated book, Planting the Oudolf
> Gardens, which can be purchased from our online [shop](https://shop.hauserwirth.com/products/planting-the-oudolf-field-at-hauser-wirth-somerset?_pos=1&_sid=68ccff787&_ss=r).
>
> Please do not hesitate to contact us again if you have any further
> questions.

Comment: Look what I found, the only is missing the name of the plants: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fouterspacesgd.wordpress.com%2F2015%2F01%2F07%2Foudolf-field-hauser-and-wirth-somerset%2F&psig=AOvVaw0b6ka-A7SyTUFKdqfHgrU0&ust=1701553337166000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBIQjRxqFwoTCIDrjqia74IDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAK

Comment: @János That's very good, you can actually read many of the names if you really try.  They are still small and upside down.  I found this site that lists many of the plants he used in that garden: https://www.houseandgarden.co.uk/article/piet-oudolf-garden-get-the-look

Comment: @János And if you are feeling bold, Mr. Oudolf lists his telephone number and address as contact information on his website: https://oudolf.com/contact

Comment: @János The garden replied to me - they want you to buy a $50 book that has the plan in it.